# How can I print 16-bit grayscale image in SDL?

Tags: c, image, sdl, grayscale

I have a structure which contains 16-bit grayscale image from scientific camera, structure is like this:

```
struct qscam_image {
    int row;
    int col;
    int max_gray; // this should be 65535
    unsigned short *data;
};
```

Then I have program which should display updated grayscale image each second or so (depending on time which takes to transfer data from camera).

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include "qscapi.h" 
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

static void render(SDL_Surface * sf)
{
    SDL_Surface * screen = SDL_GetVideoSurface();
    if(SDL_BlitSurface(sf, NULL, screen, NULL) == 0)
        SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
//initialize camera
    struct qscam_image *image = NULL;
    qscam_create_image(&image);
    qscam_init();

//initialize SDL
    SDL_Event ev;
    int active;
    /* Initialize SDL */
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not initialize SDL: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
    SDL_SetVideoMode(1900, 1080, 24, SDL_HWSURFACE);
    /* Main loop */
    active = 1;
    while(active)
    {
        /* Handle events */
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
        {
            if(ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                active = 0; /* End */
        }
        qscam_get_image(0.030, &image); //get image from camera

        /* create the image variable */
        Uint32 mask = 0xff00; // gray
        SDL_Surface* print_image = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom
            (image->data, image->col, image->row,
            16, image->col*2, mask, mask, mask, 0);

        render(print_image);
    }
    /* Exit */
    qscam_disconnect();
    qscam_destroy_image(&image);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

It works to some extent, with `mask=0x00ff` it displays random noise but that is only 8-bit image. With `mask=0xffff` nothing is displayed and with `mask=0xff00` again image is displayed, but in a way that leads me to think that the image matrix should be transposed.

First question: What is the proper way to display 16-bit grayscale image (which is in memory saved as `unsigned short[]`) using SDL and c?

And second question: Is there any easy way to transpose image matrix with SDL or do I have to write separate function?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing a sample image. I tried your code using a stub version of `qscam_create_image()` that loads a fixed 16-bit little-endian grayscale image, and it looks fine. Are you certain the image data is using the full 16 bits? If its 12 bits, you could try a mask value of 0x0ff0.

Comment: It's really 16-bit. For now I have solved it by function that recalculates image to 8-bits (just divides data by 256). Speed isn't that important.
And also the second problem is solved. I had to play with call to SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom() and swap widht and height and adjust other parameters in that function accordingly. Picture is rotated but it's ok.